# What do I need to start developing in .NET

Tags: php, asp.net

Over the last year I have moved from a beginner PHP developer to a more intermediate developer, I use Mac OS X and a local development server environment (MAMP).

I am thinking about starting to develop using the .NET framework. Can anyone give me some advice?

- What do I need to begin?
- How similar
  is .NET to PHP?
- What is the
  relationship between ASP and .NET?
- Is
  there anything novel or vital I
  should know about developing in .NET? 
  (I know .NET is written using
  microsoft technologies...)

Comment: You should split this in multiple questions. Each of your bullet-points can be made into a book by itself ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get Windows booted-up. Then you'll need [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/), and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx). Keep in mind that .NET will be very different than PHP. If you'd like to gain a bit more familiarity with .NET's way of working, while using PHP, you could examine a framework like [Prado](http://www.pradosoft.com/) which acts like a hybrid.

Out-of-the-box PHP isn't Object Oriented. .NET is. I remember my first week learning .NET I was very frustrated because I couldn't `include()` a sidebar navigation. I had to learn that controls were objects, and objects had to be created and added to other objects. It's a much better way of working (which is why many PHP developers adhere to OO-Frameworks like Kohana) as you'll eventually see.

.NET also comes in two primary languages: C# and VB.NET. If I were you, I'd stick with C# as the syntax will be most familiar coming from a PHP background - VB.NET is much more verbose, and doesn't make use of curly-braces and semicolons.

As with all programmer endeavors, keep StackOverflow bookmarked, and make heavy use of it when necessary. It will likely be your most valuable resource in learning any new programming language, or framework.

Best of luck!

Comment: He is using a Mac, so the first thing would be to get a PC :) Or use Mono ... or install Windows on a Mac

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to get a PC then I would suggest the following site:

http://www.asp.net/learn/

There are video tutorials for just about everything, including installations. They can also talk you through step by step how to do some common tasks using the .net framework.

Comment: There are things like BootCamp as well as virtualization technologies (VMWare Fusion, Parallels), so no need to get a PC to get started really.